# array of object counting consecutive sequence element with the same value

Tags: javascript

How can I transform an array like this:

```
const arrayTocheck = [
    { result: 2 },
    { result: 2 },
    { result: 0 },
    { result: 2 },
    { result: 0 },
    { result: 2 },
    { result: 2 },
    { result: 2 },
    { result: 0 },
    { result: 2 },
    { result: 2 },
    { result: 2 },
    { result: 2 },
    { result: 0 },
    { result: 2 }
];
```

to this:

```
const expectedResult = [2, 1, 3, 4, 1];
```

I want to count each group of consecutive 2's  and return those as an array.

Comment: So... how do you get the result from this input? What's happening here?

Comment: What happens if the array contains more than 2 different values for `result`? Then what should happen? Or what if the array only has one value for `result`?

Comment: @caTS, the result can be 0 or 2 with no other value

Comment: @caTS its the result of a game

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy to understand way would be to have a counter, and increment the counter inside a loop. If the item's result was not 2, then we push the counter to the results array and reset the counter. At the end, we have to push the counter again if it was not 0.

```js
const arrayToCheck=[{result:2},{result:2},{result:0},{result:2},{result:0},{result:2},{result:2},{result:2},{result:0},{result:2},{result:2},{result:2},{result:2},{result:0},{result:2}];

let i = 0;
const result = []

for (const item of arrayToCheck) {
    if (item.result === 2) i++;
    else {
        result.push(i);
        i = 0;
    }
}

if (i) result.push(i);

console.log(result);
```

---

Yet another method using some manipulation and regex! This is possible since the items we want to check are just numbers. We can transform the array into a string and then use regex to get all the consecutive 2's. Then we'll get the lengths of each of the matches as our result.

```js
const arrayToCheck=[{result:2},{result:2},{result:0},{result:2},{result:0},{result:2},{result:2},{result:2},{result:0},{result:2},{result:2},{result:2},{result:2},{result:0},{result:2}];

// 220202220222202
const string = arrayToCheck.map(({ result }) => result).join("");

const regex = /(2+)/g;

const result = Array.from(string.match(regex) ?? []).map((s) => s.length);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I like the first method more :) thanks

Comment: The first method just works if the results of `arrayToCheck` are only 2 and 0.

Comment: @FrancoA.Torres OP did say that the array can only contain 0 or 2, but you're always welcome to edit my answer to make it more general or post your own.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```js
const arrayTocheck = [
  { result: 2 },
  { result: 2 },
  { result: 0 },
  { result: 2 },
  { result: 0 },
  { result: 2 },
  { result: 2 },
  { result: 2 },
  { result: 0 },
  { result: 2 },
  { result: 2 },
  { result: 2 },
  { result: 2 },
  { result: 0 },
  { result: 2 }
]

const result = []
let lastResult = arrayTocheck[0].result
let times = 0

for (let i = 0; i < arrayTocheck.length; i++) {
  const item = arrayTocheck[i]
  if (item.result !== lastResult) {
    result.push(times)
    times = 0
  } else times++
  if (i === arrayTocheck.length - 1) result.push(times)
}

console.log(result)
```

We define a `result` variable which is an array that will contain the new transformed array. We need two temporary variables for this algorithm: `lastResult` and `times`. `lastResult` is the last result.

If in the loop, the current result is not the same as the last result then the number of times it has been the same result is pushed into the `result` array.

Comment: A little more explanation would be nice.

Comment: I just explained it.